# For loop not stopping for my neural network

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, neural-network

I'm trying to make a CNN and using a training module to train it. I'd like to specify the number of iterations it makes but am finding that it runs continuously.

Is anyone able to help me with this?

```
def train(model, epochs=10):

optimiser = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

writer = SummaryWriter()

batch_idx = 0
loss_total = 0
epoch = 0

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print('range:', range(epochs))
    for batch in train_loader:
        features, labels = batch
        prediction = model(features)

        # cf = confusion_matrix(labels, prediction)

        loss = F.cross_entropy(prediction, labels) # Loss model changes label size 
        loss_total += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        print('loss:', loss.item())
        optimiser.step() 
        optimiser.zero_grad()
        writer.add_scalar('Loss', loss.item(), batch_idx)
        batch_idx += 1
        print('epoch', epoch)
        epoch += 1 # why does this not stop???
    print('Total loss:', loss_total/batch_idx)
```

If it helps you can also find this on my GitHub: https://github.com/amosmike/facebook-market-search/blob/master/CNN.py

Thank you for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be incrementing your epoch variable at all. The epoch is being pulled from the range. Secondly, you're inside the batch loop. You probably don't want to bail after N batches.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are incrementing epoch in batch.

```py
epoch += 1 # why does this not stop???
```